How Could I update gcc version to using pandas?
I want to update my gcc version to 8.4 or higher to install pandas.
When I tried to install panads like this,
pip install pandas

It shows the error like this
Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [55 lines of output]
......
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error

    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
    exit code: 1
......
 ..\meson.build:28:4: ERROR: Problem encountered: NumPy requires GCC >= 8.4

So I tried update GCC using "mingw-get update", but it still same as before.
I download mingw in here : https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/
My GCC Version is this.
gcc(x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)8.1.0

How could I solve this problem? Please help me..!

I strongly recommend you use Conda or miniconda to install Python and related packages, so you don't need to care about tons of stuff like this and can focus on coding.
Here are the documents on how to install Conda step by step:
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html
After that, you can use this to install pandas:
conda install pandas


Got a similar error while installing numpy. Fixed it by:
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade

You check the gcc version by
gcc --version

The latest version of GCC available through apt-get depends on the repositories configured on your system. If the repositories only have an older version of GCC, you won’t get a newer version via apt-get.
